# Kalman filter in python 2-D

Tags: python, numpy, gps, kalman-filter, noise-reduction

As shown in this picture, my predicted points are following the GPS track, which has noisy points and that is not desired. Instead I want my filter to predict points that follow the road instead of the green area.

[image: 1]
I tried to implement Kalman filter on noisy GPS data to remove the jumping points or predicting missing data if GPS signal is lost. Data contains latitude and longitude. After adjusting the parameters I can see that my predicted values are very much the same as the measurements I have, which is not fulfilling the actual problem I am trying to solve. I am still at the learning
stage, so I am not sure if the parameter selection is not right or the problem lies within my Python code. I'm using QGIS for visualization of Actual and Prediction values to compare them with my real GPS data.
Here is my code:
....python...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/mun/Desktop/Research/Ny mappe/GPS_track.csv') 
df.head(1000)
lat = np.array([df.latitude])
print(lat)

long = np.array([df.longitude])
print(long)
print(len(long[0]))

for i in range(len(long)):
    print(long[i][0])

for i in range(len(lat[0])):
    print(lat[0][i])

print(len(lat[0]))
print(len(long[0]))

#length of the arrays. the arrays should always have the same length
lng=len(lat[0])
print(lng)

for index in range(lng):
    print(lat[0][index])
print(long[0][index])


for index in range (lng):
    np.array((lat[0][index], long[0][index]))

coord1 = [list(i) for i in zip (lat[0],long[0])]
print(coord1)

from pylab import *
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Kalman:
    def __init__(self, ndim):
        self.ndim    = ndim
        self.Sigma_x = eye(ndim)*1e-4     # Process noise (Q)
        self.A       = eye(ndim)           # Transition matrix which 
predict state for next time step (A)
        self.H       = eye(ndim)           # Observation matrix (H)
        self.mu_hat  = 0                    # State vector (X)
        self.cov     = eye(ndim)*0.01            # Process Covariance (P)
        self.R       = .001    # Sensor noise covariance matrix / 
measurement error (R)

    def update(self, obs):

        # Make prediction
        self.mu_hat_est = dot(self.A,self.mu_hat)
        self.cov_est = dot(self.A,dot(self.cov,transpose(self.A))) + 
self.Sigma_x

        # Update estimate
        self.error_mu = obs - dot(self.H,self.mu_hat_est)
        self.error_cov = dot(self.H,dot(self.cov,transpose(self.H))) + 
self.R
        self.K = 
dot(dot(self.cov_est,transpose(self.H)),linalg.inv(self.error_cov))
        self.mu_hat = self.mu_hat_est + dot(self.K,self.error_mu)
        if ndim>1:
            self.cov = dot((eye(self.ndim) - 
dot(self.K,self.H)),self.cov_est)
        else:
            self.cov = (1-self.K)*self.cov_est 

if __name__ == "__main__":      
    #print "***** 1d ***********"
    ndim = 1
    nsteps = 3
    k = Kalman(ndim)    
    mu_init=array([54.907134])
    cov_init=0.001*ones((ndim))
    obs = random.normal(mu_init,cov_init,(ndim, nsteps))
    for t in range(ndim,nsteps):
        k.update(obs[:,t])
        print ("Actual: ", obs[:, t], "Prediction: ", k.mu_hat_est)

coord_output=[]

for coordinate in coord1:
    temp_list=[]
    ndim = 2
    nsteps = 100
    k = Kalman(ndim)    
    mu_init=np.array(coordinate)
    cov_init=0.0001*ones((ndim))
    obs = zeros((ndim, nsteps))
    for t in range(nsteps):
        obs[:, t] = random.normal(mu_init,cov_init)
    for t in range(ndim,nsteps):
        k.update(obs[:,t])
        print ("Actual: ", obs[:, t], "Prediction: ", k.mu_hat_est[0])
    temp_list.append(obs[:, t])
    temp_list.append(k.mu_hat_est[0])
    
    print("temp list")
    print(temp_list)
    coord_output.append(temp_list)

for coord_pair in coord_output:
    print(coord_pair[0])
    print(coord_pair[1])
    print("--------")
print(line_actual)

print(coord_output)


df2= pd.DataFrame(coord_output)
print(df2)

Actual = df2[0] 
Prediction = df2[1]
print (Actual)
print(Prediction)


Actual_df = pd.DataFrame(Actual)
Prediction_df = pd.DataFrame(Prediction)
print(Actual_df)
print(Prediction_df)


Actual_coord = pd.DataFrame(Actual_df[0].to_list(), columns = ['latitude', 
'longitude'])
Actual_coord.to_csv('C:/Users/mun/Desktop/Research/Ny 
mappe/Actual_noise.csv')

Prediction_coord = pd.DataFrame(Prediction_df[1].to_list(), columns = 
['latitude', 'longitude'])
Prediction_coord.to_csv('C:/Users/mun/Desktop/Research/Ny 
mappe/Prediction_noise.csv')

print (Actual_coord)
print (Prediction_coord)


Actual_coord.plot(kind='scatter',x='longitude',y='latitude',color='red')
plt.show()
Prediction_coord.plot(kind='scatter',x='longitude',y='latitude',
color='green')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please explain more clearly what the expected results are and what you actually get.

Comment: Please format you code. Currently it is not a valid Python code because indentations are messed up

Comment: I have just formated, hope it makes sense now...I used jupyter notebook for coding..

Comment: @M-Chen-3  more explaination along results are added